# Typescript extend prototype of external library

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

Given a library `l` that exports a class `C` in the namespace `N` like this:

```js
export namespace N {
   export class C {
      public function f1(){return true}
   } 
}
```

and can be used with

```js
import {N} from 'l'

console.log(new N().C.f1())
```

I can easily do

```js
//@ts-ignore
N.C.prototype.f2 = ()=>return false

//@ts-ignore
console.log(new N().C.f2()
```

But how can I tell typescript that I extended the prototype and get rid of the `//@ts-ignore`

All solutions I found described how to extend objects in the global namespace like `Array` or `String`

**Additional Info**

The actual library I want to extend is `@js-temporal/polyfill` because the `Duration.compare()` method which returns `1`, `0` or `-1` is fairly unreadable and I want to add a `Duration.greaterThan()` method

Comment: if `Duration.compare()` returns `1` does that not mean greater than?

Comment: `Duration.compare(a,b)` does work, but what does 1 mean, is it greater or lesser? and which is greater, `a` or `b`? Writing `a.greaterThan(b) // =>true` is just way more readable and semantic. So you could call it syntatic sugar what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You could read the docs on `Duration.compare()` to see? Seems like a "reinventing the wheel" situation by extending the package for something it already does. You could even wrap the `Duration.compare()` to get the syntax you want

Comment: Thats like saying using javascript instead of bytecode is like reinventing the wheel, surely bytecode does everything javascript does and I could read the x86 bytecode doc. Nevertheless thats not what my question was about, I wanted to know how I could do this in general, not just js-temporal. Then lets's say for the sake of the example I want to add a function `Duration.divide()` which devides two durations